# How to get local notification in Android while Application stop?

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing one Android Application which uses Local Notification
by using Alarm Manager and BroadCast Receiver. I am receiving notification without any error in default. I am not receiving notification, If i Force Stop my application by using settings-> Application-> ManageApplication-> MyApplication-> ForceStop. My code is

To schedule Event

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "O'Doyle Rules!");
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

My BroadCast Receiver

```
try 
        {
             Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
             String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
             Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Intent i=new Intent(context,AlertActivity.class);
             i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
             context.startActivity(i);     
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {     
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please give me some advise to solve my problem. Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you show your logcat errors so I try to find where you get wrong

Comment: I am not receiving any log cat errors

Answer (score 0):

can you explain it a bit more ... i guess without using any background service or app widget kind of thing how you can expect that your application will continue to run even after force close ???

Comment: 1. After you set the alarm and kill the alarm clock( using taskiller) the alarm never goes off. why? I thought this was the idea behind intent and broadcast receivers. Also, can android kill the alarm because it require resources? is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, you must do the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTimeInMillis(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
```

...and so on...

Answer (score 0):

API forcestoppackage will cancel alarms associated with the package
So nothing will happen in the future.

forcestopPackage() will send a broadcast with action "package_restart", AlarmManagerService listen this broadcast and remove all alarm set by the app which is force stopped.